# Python! difference of a = a.sort() and only a.sort()

Tags: python

For Example:

```py
a = [1, 3, 5, 4, 2]    
a = a.sort()
print(a)
```

Output:

```py
None
```

---

```py
a = [1, 3, 5, 4, 2]
a.sort()
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

My question is why does `a = a.sort()` reslt in `None` rather than `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`? But without `a=` it gives me `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Thank you

Comment: Because [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) returns `None`. It modifies the list in-place.

Comment: Try `a = sorted(a)`, this function will return a sorted copy of the original list

Answer (score 1):

Because, `a.sort` returns `None`, and you are overwriting `a`'s value with that `None`. The list will still be sorted, because `list.sort` does that in place. `sorted(list)` does the inverse : It copies the list, sorts that copy, and returns it. You then have to assign the list to it.